# Visual Studio Code: Attach to Unity process for debugging C++ based dll

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, gdb

I have a Unity project that uses some C++ code via a DLL compiled in a separate project.
Can I attach the visual studio code debugger to my Unity project such that I can debug the DLL's source code using break points?

Here are some things I tried so far:

- in Unity: Press "Pause", then press "Start" to immediately pause the game after starting it (in order to get time to attach vs code)
- compile DLL using debug symbols
- in VS Code: create a `launch.json` like this

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to process",
            "type":"clr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }]
}
```

--> this should allow me to pick the process I want to connect to interactively

- VS Code: click on "Attach to process" -> search for my project name -> returns a process based on `my/path/to/Unity.exe`
  --> attaching seems to work, but when I "unpause" my Unity game it never hits a break point.

Is my launch.json wrong?

Some additional info:

- I'm using bazel to compile my c++ library project via command line (not sure if relevant?)
- Usually when debugging C++ in VS code my launch.json has an entry `sourceMap` which directs the debugger to the root of my source files. Not sure if anything similar would be needed here as well?

**Moving forward**
Meanwhile I've refactored my launch.json a bit. Thanks to a comment I assume `"type" : "clr"` stand for [Common Language Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) which seems to be for debugging scripting languages but not C/C++. So I changed it to `"type":"cppdbg"`. After installing gdb via Msys2, I'm referencing the path to that gdb in the launch.json. This is an updated version of my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to process",
            "type":"cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/Packages/com.github.homuler.mediapipe/Runtime/Plugins/mediapipe_c.dll",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        }]
}
```

Spoiler: It's still not working, but inside VS Code debug console / terminal I see some output when I start the game in Unity editor. So there seems to be some traffic between VS Code and Unity at least.
One new problem:

- with second version of launch.json, C++ breakpoints are grey with the info message "Attempting to bind the breakpoint...."

Comment: I don't think "clr" is a correct debugger type for attaching to process with native dll.

Comment: did you check this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71464736/how-to-attach-visual-studio-to-unity-in-order-to-debug-a-native-dll

Comment: @user7860670 can you expand? What else should I use? Do you have a working example of such a configuration file?

Comment: @Morion I have checked that thread, but appart from recommending to "not attach to a paused Unity game" (which didn't solve my problem), it leads down a rabbit hole of multiple links. I'm still struggling to get a straight and concise answer out of them. Some of the proposed solution use VS instead of VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

While I couldn't figure out a solution for VS Code, I found a solution for

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 RC (64-bit), installed with

  - Desktop development with C++
  - Universal Windows Platform development
  - note: this is not the standalone VS shipped with Unity (which is VS 2019)

the solution goes roughly like this

- compile C++ DLL library with debug flags

  - since in my case the compilation was done using bazel, I cannot even say which compiler was used, but it doesn't seem to matter
- Open VS -> File open -> Select folder that contains C++ source code (doesn't have to be the same folder as the Unity project)
- Set breakpoint in any .cc file (that is accessed from Unity)
- Launch Unity
- In VS (top menu bar) click on Debug -> Attach to Process

  - in process list search for Unity.exe (there should only be one entry)
    [image]
  - above that list is an option "Attach to:" -> Select -> "Native"
    [image]
- Launch Game inside Unity Editor

--> the game should now break when hitting the breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

The C++ DLL library Project in VS be compiled debug first, also need add the [/Zi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/958x11bc(v=vs.140)) parameter.

Follow steps:

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
2. Click the C/C++ folder.
3. Click the General property page.
4. Modify the Debug Information Format property.